# How to get id´s and class of input element of a certain div by class in Selenium

Tags: selenium, input, find

I have this html part of code.

```
<div class="tbody">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">
            <input type="text" id="my_id_1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">
            <input type="text" id="my_id_2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">
            <input type="text" id="my_id_3">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">
            <input type="text" id="my_id_4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Selenium I need to find all ids of `input type="text"` that are contained in the `div` with the `class="tbody"`.

Comment: Programming language?

Comment: `div.tbody input[type=text]` as selector and then get the id

Comment: I am using java language, can you tell me how to use your ideas with syntax. Thanks.

Comment: @S.S.N try with the provided answer..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using java, try using `By.cssSelector()` as below :-

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.tbody input[type = 'text']"))
for(WebElement el : elements) 
{
   String id = el.getAttribute("id");
   String class = el.getAttribute("class");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Java` you can use below piece of code.

```
List<WebElement> allInputs = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='tbody']//input[@type='text']"));
for(WebElement eachid : allInputs) {
    System.out.println(eachid.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code doesn't guarantee that all the `input`s are only those under the `div` with `class = "tbody"` as OP requested.